# Is it a good practice to use Google Cloud App Engine + Firebase + Cloud Functions to serve HTML cache?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Gev here from Ucraft.

I am reaching out to ask you for some help with ideas on how we can realise the following:

Ucraft is a website builder, built on PHP on the backend, hosted on Google Cloud App Engine.

Now we want to develop a caching mechanism for our public views(Pure HTML hosted in Cloud Storage).

- As our frontend websites are multilingual we will need cache for available languages, for which we are thinking to generate HTML cache on a certain step, if cache is not available, using the lang prefix, like Folder: Cache > www.aaa.com > en_GB > index.html/about-us.html…
- As out frontend also supports location based layout changes, we will need to generate cache, like this: Cache Folder > www.aaa.com > en_GB > Global > index.html or smth like this: Cache Folder > www.aaa.com > en_GB > uk > index.html, which means that this folder includes cache specific to UK…

#

Scenario: As we need to detect the end user’s location to understand which cache to serve, we are thinking to use Cloud Functions + Firebase. In Firebase we will store DBs that describe if a website has got any location based cache(this will help us to determine the path of the cached folder).  In Cloud Functions we want to write a small piece of code, a kind of a tiny load balancer with a logic, that will get the users location from the initial request, check in Firebase, if the website has any location specific cache, if the location of the user and the cache are the same it will serve the cache in the response. If there is no cache available, it will turn to App Engine, Get the HTML, cache it in Cloud Storage, and serve te request

Question: Is this a good practice to store the cache in Cloud Storage as html?

Thank you!